# How to export all contacts from Outlook 2007 as vcard?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, export, vcard

Is there a way to save all my Outook 2007 contacts as vcards?

There is no option under menu File > Import and Export...

One can export each contact one by one by selecting the contact and choosing "Save As..." vcard. But that's not what I want. I am looking for a bulk operation.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a hack but it works:

- First select all your contact (ctrl+A)
- Right-click and select "Send as Business Card" (this will create a new email for you with all vcf cards attached. This can take a long time, be patient!
- In the new email select all the attachement (ctrl+A in the "Attached" field)
- Drag and drop the attachements on a fold on your computer... Et voilà!

**Bonus tip:** you can consolidate your vcf files into a single file (for gmail import for example). Just start a command prompt, go into the folder that contains you new vcards and type: `COPY *.vcf MyNewFIle.vcf`

If you cannot drag the attachments from the draft mail change the mail format to HTML and retry. If that fails then send it to yourself and get them attached once you receive it (or check in sent mail)

Comment: Sometime, I wish I could vote up more than once... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tested solution:

1. press ctrl+a to select all contacts
2. drag and drop to the folder where you want the vcards to be saved.

that's all.

Comment: I just tried that and I get an *.msg file for each selected contact, not a vcard. When I open the file in a text editor it is binary, not a plain text vcard. The same happens with Outlook 2010. Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: I think this is how Outlook 2003 behaved.

Answer (score -2):

1. Follow the Help instructions in Outlook to export your Contacts as a CSV file
2. Copy this file to a computer that has Windows Contacts (e.g. Windows 7 or XP I think)
3. Follow the Help instructions in Windows 7 / XP to import Contacts (from a CSV file)
4. Follow the Help instructions in Windows 7 / XP to export Contacts (in vCard format)

Answer (score -2):

Easy steps:

1. Open Outlook contacts
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and copy all contacts to a folder
3. Un-hide file extensions in folder options
4. Change file extension from `.msg` to `.vcf`

   - open a command prompt
   - `cd` to the folder in which the contacts are
   - type `ren *.msg *.vcf`

That's it, all contacts have been changed to VCF files.

Comment: The resulting files are not true vCards, but some kind of binary format.

Answer (score -2):

Open up your contact of choice.
Select File/saveas/export to vCard.
Once you select export to vCard, save that vCard into a folder where you will remember the location.