# Transfer Saved Outlook Contacts From PC to Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: microsoft-outlook, android, contacts, data-transfer

I have 700+ contacts backed up on my PC in Outlook Item (.msg) format. I wan't to transfer these contacts to my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge phone but can't work out the following:

1. What folder they should be put in on the device
2. What format the contacts should be in
3. How to change the format so the device recognises the contacts

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

A general solution which I used a long time ago. Perhaps there is an alternative, easier way now.

1. Doesn't really matter as long as you can navigate to it.
2. VCard (.vcf)
3. See [How to export all contacts from Outlook 2007 as vcard?](https://superuser.com/questions/150513/how-to-export-all-contacts-from-outlook-2007-as-vcard).

Answer (score 0):

You can use gmail to do this.

1. Export Outlook contatcs
2. Import them to gmail
3. Sync your phone with google